# Drupal 7 db_insert and DEFAULT column values

Tags: mysql, pdo, drupal-7

Trying to insert a DEFAULT value into a MySQL database column
Simple example

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 id int(11) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 test_date date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

On mysql i can do

```
INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES(1);
```

works fine

Now i go to drupal 7 and do the following

```
$data = array('id' => 1);
$result = db_insert('test')->fields($data)->execute();
```

i get the below error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field &#039;name&#039; doesn&#039;t have a default value: INSERT INTO {test} (id) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1 )
```

The "sql mode" on the MySQL is set to '' (empty string)

Questions

1. what is the reason for this error to occur? is drupal (or the PDO) expecting to have insert values for all columns?
2. lets say i want to insert a MySQL DEFAULT value into the date column , how would i do it using db_insert?

Thanks

========================================================================
**Explanation after digging in:**

- drupal 7 does not use a date or datetime fields
- all its date are stored in INT fields as Unix timestamps
- this may be because D7 wants to keep date handling independent of how different databases implement date time fields
- i think this is a good practice to allow applications to handle conversion and display the timestamp int field
- will happly acomodate up till UNIX time 4294967295 is 02/07/2106
  6:28am GMT. ( the int being unsigned )

to see the allowed types you can check it here

- file: schema.inc
- function: getFieldTypeMap()

  ```
  'varchar:normal'  => 'VARCHAR',
  'char:normal'     => 'CHAR',

  'text:tiny'       => 'TINYTEXT',
  'text:small'      => 'TINYTEXT',
  'text:medium'     => 'MEDIUMTEXT',
  'text:big'        => 'LONGTEXT',
  'text:normal'     => 'TEXT',

  'serial:tiny'     => 'TINYINT',
  'serial:small'    => 'SMALLINT',
  'serial:medium'   => 'MEDIUMINT',
  'serial:big'      => 'BIGINT',
  'serial:normal'   => 'INT',

  'int:tiny'        => 'TINYINT',
  'int:small'       => 'SMALLINT',
  'int:medium'      => 'MEDIUMINT',
  'int:big'         => 'BIGINT',
  'int:normal'      => 'INT',

  'float:tiny'      => 'FLOAT',
  'float:small'     => 'FLOAT',
  'float:medium'    => 'FLOAT',
  'float:big'       => 'DOUBLE',
  'float:normal'    => 'FLOAT',

  'numeric:normal'  => 'DECIMAL',

  'blob:big'        => 'LONGBLOB',
  'blob:normal'     => 'BLOB',
  ```

other function you may be interested to look ( the logic trickles down like this )

- function createTableSql()
- function createFieldSql()
- function processField()
- function: getFieldTypeMap()

if you pass anything other than these, a malformed table sql will stop you from creating the table itself

if you already have database fields with date and datetime fields in mysql, then you may need to create a timestamp field to make it compatible with D7

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that SQL MODE not set globally, but is set in the user session, try to get this information, execute this query -

```
SELECT @@SESSION.SQL_MODE;
```

Comment: the SESSION SQL_MODE is also set to ""